# Printing whole folder

Tags: c++, printing, wxwidgets

This is my first time ever asking something here, so I apologize if I do anything wrong.

I have a problem with a program I am trying to write.
What I want to do is have the user pick a folder and the program prints all the documents (mostly a mix of pdf and word files) without any more user interaction.

And to make matters worse, the system I am working in is severely restricted, so my testing possibilities are limited.

Basically, what I want is to do some sort of equivalent of right-click printing in code. Or copy a file to the printer queue.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very grateful. Google isn't much help. I tried executing the print command, but it doesn't do what I want it to.

My current attempt:

```
void folderFrame::onOpen(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
    int listLength;
    wxArrayString fileList;
    wxString pFolder, pCommand;

    chooseFolder = new wxDirDialog(this, _("Please choose folder from which to print:"), "", wxDD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wxDD_DIR_MUST_EXIST, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize,"");
    if (chooseFolder->ShowModal() == wxID_OK) //User chooses folder
    {
        int pResult;
        pFolder = chooseFolder->GetPath();
        wxDir::GetAllFiles(pFolder, &fileList, "", wxDIR_FILES);  //Get all files in folder
        listLength = fileList.GetCount();   //Get number of files                            
        for(int i = 0; i < listLength; i++)  //For each file...
        {
            pCommand = _T("print /d:\\\\app065\\300408_P18 "); //Make command to execute
            pCommand.append(fileList[i]);
            theText->AppendText(fileList[i]);   //The text ctrl is to check what commands I actually execute
            theText->AppendText("\n");          //And to check if the system return errors
            theText->AppendText(pCommand);
            theText->AppendText("\n");
            pResult = wxExecute(pCommand, wxEXEC_SYNC | wxEXEC_SHOW_CONSOLE | wxEXEC_NOEVENTS, NULL, NULL); //Print!!!!
            theText->AppendText(wxString::Format(wxT("%i\n"), pResult));
        }
    }
}
```

print .... prints only one file.

copy only returns 0 (success error code, but nothing happens)

So, here I am stuck. Any help getting forward would be greatly appreciated.

/Mike

Comment: printing something depends on your target platform.Add the details about your target platform.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually isn't really hard, since your path hints at Windows. The second parameter of `ShellExecute` can be `"print"`.

Comment: Right, it wasn't that hard, but totally overlooked somehow. THANK YOU!